# Mysql converts varchar to year while update

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask-mysql

I have a query for updating varchar time field and I don't want to keep them in DATE format. My string date format is `yyyy-mm-dd` is `2018-05-13`.

```
query = "UPDATE SchedulePlaylist
    SET start = %s ,end = %s
    WHERE playlist_id = %s AND schedule_id = %s" % (
                str(start), str(end), playlist_id, schedule_id)
```

[image: This are contents of functions after updating the database.]

[image: But my actual table looks like this]

how can I prevent this conversion. I am using python and flask_mysqldb connector

Comment: It might help if you show us the raw MySQL update query you intend to run.  At a glance, it doesn't sound right that you are trying to mix dates with strings; you should keep your date information in date/time columns, and not varchar columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper approach is to use *parameters* to pass the values in.  This could get awkward, because of the date/string issues.

The naive solution in your case is to add single quotes around values:

```
query = "UPDATE SchedulePlaylist
    SET start = '%s', end = '%s'
    WHERE playlist_id = %s AND schedule_id = %s" % (
                str(start), str(end), playlist_id, schedule_id)
```

Your code is treating 2018-04-30 as arithmetic and producing 1984.  The single quote cause them to be represented as a string.

What you should really do is fix the table, so the columns have the correct type.  A string stored as YYYY-MM-DD is a reasonable type *if you have to store the date as a string*.  Otherwise use `date`.  However, that doesn't fix your update problem.

The better solution is to use parameters, and that is simple.  The parameters go in the `execute` call:

```
query = """
UPDATE SchedulePlaylist
    SET start = ?, end = ?
    WHERE playlist_id = ? AND schedule_id = ?
""";

cursor.execute(query, (str(start), str(end), playlist_id, schedule_id));
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . That is the issue.  This isn't a prepared statement.  `query` is a string in Python.  Python is simply doing the substitution.  See the edit I added.  If you look at the question, you'll what `query` really contains -- an arithmetic expression rather than a string.